# Showing elements depending on which mat-radio-button is checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having issues figuring out how to reveal and hide elements based on what radio button is selected. This is the pseudocode of what I have so far:

```
  <mat-radio-button [value]="0">BUTTON A</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1">BUTTON B</mat-radio-button>
  <h1 *ngIf="buttonA === '0'">Button A is selected</h1>
  <h1*ngIf="buttonB=== '1'">Button B is selected</h1>
```

When radio button A is selected, it should reveal "Button A" h1. When button B is selected, it should reveal "Button B" h1 while disappearing "Button A" h1 and vice versa.

My assumption is that both h1 tags will need ngIf in order to know when to appear / disappear depending on which checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options here.

> First Approach (Using ngModel)

using ngModel on mat-radio-group essentially keeping a component variable in sync with the template. You can do something like this

something.component.html

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="0">BUTTON A</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1">BUTTON B</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 0">Button A is selected</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 1">Button B is selected</h1>
```

and in something.component.ts declare the variable

```
selectedValue: number;
```

> Second Approach (using change event)

something.component.html

```
<mat-radio-group (change)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="0">BUTTON A</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1">BUTTON B</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 0">Button A is selected</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 1">Button B is selected</h1>
```

change event is triggered whenever any selection of radio button inside the radio group is changed. Which calls a function onChange.

something.component.ts

```
export class Something {
  selectedValue: number;

  onChange(event: MatRadioChange) {
    this.selectedValue = event.value;
  }
}
```

onChange function basically assigns the value selected to the selectedValue variable

Although you can capture the change event at the mat-radio-button level if you don't want to use mat-radio-group I wouldn't recommend it. You have to capture change event for each mat-radio-button you add. Generally enclosing mat-radio-group is considered a best practise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically how mat-radio-button works, however, normally radio buttons set a common value that can be inspected. I don't see anything in your code that is setting the values `buttonA` or `buttonB`. So I would expect you are not seeing either h1 element.

You need to inspect whatever field `[value]="0" and [value]="1" are setting.

A quick look and you should likely be using mat-radio-group to contain the buttons see

https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-groups

> Radio groups Radio-buttons should typically be placed inside of an
>  unless the DOM structure would make that impossible
> (e.g., radio-buttons inside of table cells). The radio-group has a
> value property that reflects the currently selected radio-button
> inside of the group.
>
> Individual radio-buttons inside of a radio-group will inherit the name
> of the group.

The key part here is "The radio-group has a value property that reflects the currently selected radio-button inside of the group"

This is the value you want to compare against for your *ngIf statements. So something like this

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="selectedValue">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="0">BUTTON A</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="1">BUTTON B</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 0">Button A is selected</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="selectedValue === 1">Button B is selected</h1>
```